# Свой querySelector не работает как надо

Tags: javascript, prototype

Есть html:

```
<table id="table"><template></template></table>
```

Я задал такую конструкцию:

```
function gId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

Node.prototype.qS = function(s){return this.querySelector(s)}
```

В коде пишу:

```
var t=gId('table');
console.log(t.qS("template"));
```

выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: t.qS is not a function

где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

не стоит модифицировать `Node` или `Object`.
лучше написать вот так:

```js
function gId(id) {
  let el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (el && !el.qS) el.qS = qS.bind(el)
  else throw new Error('что-то не так')
  return el
}

function qS(s) {
  return this.querySelector(s)
}

const t = gId('table');
console.log(t.qS("template"));
```

```html
<table id="table"><template></template></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Объекты DOM с точки зрения javascript являются exotic object. В них некоторые языковые механизмы могут отсутствовать или работать странно в зависимости от браузера.

Если вам важна поддержка всех браузеров - то придется использовать другие механизмы. Например, можно обойтись обычной функцией:

```
function qS (el, selector) {
    return el.querySelector(selector);
}
```

Или же можно сделать свой класс-обертку.